# Mod_Rewrite for only one folder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want top be able to type `http://website.com/new` which will rewrite to `http://website.com/index.php?view=new`, but I only want the `new` directory to be "re-written".

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^new/ /index.php?view=new [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `top` in the rule, isn't `new` the one you want to map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^new/?$    /index.php?view=new [L,NC]
```